# What is the right way to remove a mesh completely from the scene in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I remove meshes from three.js scene completely without causing memory leaks. I could find that loading the same models again and again causes the browser to crash, so it seems like the memory is not being deallocated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `dispose` method on the geometry and material. Also, ensure that nothing is holding references to these objects, as that will prevent garbage collection.

```
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
scene.add(myMesh);
//...
scene.remove(myMesh);
myMesh.geometry.dispose();
myMesh.material.dispose();
myMesh = undefined;
```

Comment: I know this is old, but imagine if the mesh was an property of an object in an array. if you clear the array, do you sitll need the = undefined? I noticed way less GC when I implement your suggestion

Comment: I don't know why you are seeing _reduced_ GC. You _should_ see the same _or more_ as your array-clearing method. That said, I don't recall to which version of three.js this applied (I should have noted it in my post, sorry). What I mean is, this may no longer be a problem in the current version, and your array-clearing method may be sufficient. Perform a heap snapshot before and after each clearing method to compare the deltas of the reduction in `Geometry`/`BufferGeometry` objects

Comment: if you got a texture map in your material. You need to call dispose function for texture as well

Comment: Reminder: the `remove` method must be called on the object's parent, not necessarily your primary `THREE.Scene` instance (e.g., for an object in a collada scene). Using `myMesh.parent.remove(myMesh)` will ensure the correct target. Also I believe calling `renderer.renderLists.dispose()` may (will?) prevent memory leaks.

Comment: @Synexis Thanks for the update. I think at this point, this question is so old (5 years) that it should be taken with a some doubt that it is still 100% correct. I wouldn't fault someone for asking the question anew to get an up-to-date answer. :)

Comment: @TheJim01, I think your answer is actually still relevant to the current build of three.js. It certainly pointed me in the right direction to solve my issue (thank you, by the way!). Regardless, I like to add notes in case others come across similar issues in their search for answers (they're not necessary directed toward OP). Cheers.