# How to remove an object from the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to remove some cylinders that are in scene so i can put new ones in another position.

This is how I place the cylinders (this works just showing so you understand what I am trying to do).

```
for (i = 0; i < aantalLangs; i++) { 

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( (langsDiameter * scale), (langsDiameter * scale) , langsLengte * scale , 20 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffe26f} );
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( cylinder );

cylinder.position.set( 0 , 0 ,onderRandRooster);
onderRandRooster -= (langsMaas * scale);
cylinder.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
}
```

And I use this function to remove them.

```
function ClearMesh(){
scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(cylinder));
scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(cylinder2));
}
```

I want to use this button to remove the cylinders.

```
<button onclick="ClearMesh();">Clear mesh</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to remove a mesh completely from the scene in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694372/what-is-the-right-way-to-remove-a-mesh-completely-from-the-scene-in-three-js)

Comment: The answers on that post won't work for me, so I hoped someone could give me an answer that does work if I post the question myself. Also I can't comment on that post so can't ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use  `Object3D.getObjectByName()`, it's necessary to apply a string as a parameter. To be more precise, `Object3D.name` which you currently don't set in your application. Something like this should work:

```
// in your for loop

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cylinder.name = 'cylinder' + i;

// in your ClearMesh() function

scene.remove( scene.getObjectByName( 'cylinder1' ) );
```

Besides, consider to reuse your material and geometry when creating your cylinder meshes if they have the same properties. Just declare them outside of the `for` loop. Otherwise you should use the respective `.dispose()` methods in order to free internal resources of the engine when you remove a cylinder. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730686/5250847 for more details.

`three.js R103`

Comment: Still nothing is happening for me :/

Comment: Please demonstrate your issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/). Otherwise it will be hard to provide more help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rqa1t0zn/3/ here is an example of what i want to do.

Comment: just leave the 2 empty on both sides, and this project still needs some work but i just want this to work first so its easier for me to finish this project

Comment: add the javascript code to the html code then u will see my scene

Comment: I've update your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/va7frj4k/1/. You did still not use `Object3D.getObjectByName()` correctly. Anyway, I've change your code so that your cylinders are marked with a custom flag in `Object3D.userData`. When you want to remove them from the scene graph, you traverse through it, save all respective cylinders in an array and then perform a single `scene.remove()`.